# Clicking on element after mouse move in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```
<a class="menu-item js-add-to-basket pizzaAddDefault js-change-ingredients js-add-pizza-to-basket" id="ph-add-to-basket-61504822" data-id="61504822" upsell-id="" href="/amrest-pizzahut/products#category/pizza" style="height: auto;">
            <div class="ph-order-on-preview">
                <button class="btn btn--primary">Zamów online</button>
            </div>
            <div id="ph-add-to-basket-61504822" class="box-counter ph-product-in-basket hidden" data-id="61504822">
                <span class="ph-products-in-basket-number">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item__content">
                <h5>
                    <!-- 
                            <div class="ph-menu-favorite js-favourite" sec:authorize="!isAnonymous()">
                                <img th:src="@{/images/favourite-unchecked.png}" class="unchecked" alt="Nie ulubiona" />
                            </div>
                     -->
                    VEGE DELUX
                </h5>
                <p>
                    37,99 PLN
                </p>
                <p class="menu-item__description"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item__image">
                <img src="https://ocs-pl.oktawave.com/v1/AUTH_876e5729-f8dd-45dd-908f-35d8bb716177/amrest-web-ordering/GRD4/GRD4590/Smaki%20Premium/Pizza_vege_medium_450x450.png" alt="VEGE DELUX">
            </div>
        </a>
```

Above there's code from my site, i need to move mouse button on this class, and next press 'zamów online' button

I have following locators for this item:

```
    @FindBy (css="#ph-add-to-basket-61504822") WebElement firstpizza;
    @FindBy (css="#ph-add-to-basket-61504822 .ph-order-on-preview button") WebElement pizzabutton;
```

and functions

```
public void clickPizzaBasket() {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(firstpizza);
    System.out.print("moved");
    pizzabutton.click();
}
```

executing this function i get org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible on pizzabutton.click() line

In which way i should access to 'zamów online' buttons?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page there're more than 1 element with id in @FindBy (css=1 and css=2 versions)
Its working if I use List instead of WebElement

```
    @FindBy (css=".pizza.show h5") List <WebElement> namesOfPizzas;
    @FindBy (css=".pizza.show button") List <WebElement> pizzaOrderButtons;
```

and function:

```
    public void clickOrderFirstPizza() throws InterruptedException {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    action.moveToElement(namesOfPizzas.get(0)).build().perform();       
    System.out.print("moved");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pizzaOrderButtons.get(0)));
    pizzaOrderButtons.get(0).click();
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

How about this one -

```
 @FindBy (id="ph-add-to-basket-61504822") WebElement firstpizza;
 @FindBy (xpath="//button[contains(text(), 'online')]") WebElement pizzabutton;

    public void clickPizzaBasket() {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(firstpizza).perform(); 
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pizzabutton));
        pizzabutton.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@FindBy (css="#ph-add-to-basket-61504822") WebElement firstpizza;
@FindBy (css="#ph-add-to-basket-61504822 > div.ph-order-on-preview > button") WebElement pizzabutton;

public void clickPizzaBasket() {
    Thread.sleep(2000); // add pause
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(firstpizza).perform(); // you forgot to perform the action
    System.out.print("moved");
    Thread.sleep(2000); // add pause
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pizzabutton));
    pizzabutton.click();
}
```

Comment: On your new locator with xpath: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"span[contains(., 'Zamów online')]"}.If i added perform to my action - nothing changes, still org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Are you sure that firstpizza id is static?

Comment: Yes, this locator is static

Comment: Does it print 'moved' and then throw exception?

Comment: Try my xpath one more time, I had an error. The xpath is updated

Comment: yes, after printing moved throws exception, but it's look like mouse are not moved. On your new xpath locator: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: button[contains(., 'Zamów online')]' (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: and also org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"button[contains(., 'Zamów online')]"}.         In situation when i manually moved mouse above class, and button is visible, it should click on it? Or it will be only clicked when computer use selenium for mouse moving?

Comment: Thats already better. One second, I'll add a path to firstpizza

Comment: Please try my updated code, if it won't work, please check in the brwoser which elements you are getting with this xPaths

Comment: On first pizza: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"button[contains(., 'Zamów online')]/parent::div/parent::a"}